# real time and sim time in gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo, gazebo-plugins, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!!!

I have little problem with Gazebo. How I can make the sim_time equal to real time?, in another words, How I can do for what 1 seconds in sim_time equal to 1 seconds in real time?

Thanks!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30290/real-time-and-sim-time-in-gazebo/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2012-03-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In your [`*.world`](https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/simulator_gazebo/branches/simulator_gazebo-1.4/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world) file, add an `<updateRate/>` tag under `<physics:ode>` and set its value to -1, for example:

```
<physics:ode>
  <stepTime>0.001</stepTime>
  <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
  <cfm>0.0000000001</cfm>
  <erp>0.2</erp>
  <quickStep>true</quickStep>
  <quickStepIters>10</quickStepIters>
  <quickStepW>1.3</quickStepW>
  <contactMaxCorrectingVel>100.0</contactMaxCorrectingVel>
  <contactSurfaceLayer>0.001</contactSurfaceLayer>
  <updateRate>-1</updateRate>
</physics:ode>
```

That should throttle sim time to real time.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on 2012-03-28**:
Thanks!!!

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-06-25**:
Has this been tested in Fuerte? I am not able to get anything except faster than real time behavior.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-10**:
How much faster than realtime do you see @phil0stine? (I've noticed  factors  [0.97-1.32] )

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-10-10**:
I take that back.. when left to run long enough, the factors rise. Maybe it's time for a new question?

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-10-12**:
Interestingly, I can get gazebo empty.world to set sim_time to real_time  when update_rate is greater than zero, but not when it's less than zero (it runs about 10x in that case)